# Powershell expose values of ParameterizedProperty

Tags: powershell

I am working on a com+ script, but I have encountered something I am unclear on.
How can I figure out what values are exposed via a paramaterizedProprty method? I figure this must be a hashtable or something.

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1") 
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")  
$applications.Populate() 

foreach ($application in $applications) {

    $components = $applications.GetCollection("Components",$application.key)
    $components.Populate()
    foreach ($component in $components)
    {
        # What other values are available besides "DLL"
        $dllName = $component.Value("DLL")
     }
}
```

> ```
> PS C:\Users\myself> $component|gm -MemberType ParameterizedProperty
>
>
>    TypeName: System.__ComObject#{6eb22871-8a19-11d0-81b6-00a0c9231c29}
>
> Name  MemberType            Definition                         
> ----  ----------            ----------                         
> Value ParameterizedProperty Variant Value (string) {get} {set}
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that unless you have the docs, you can't figure out what possible values are available to the collection. All those values are just strings.

You have a full list at this location: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688285(v=vs.85).aspx